# Stacking namespaces can't be referenced just like any other element?

Tags: c#, inheritance

So here is a snippet I made where one namespace in inside another (B is inside A).
Usually when you use 'using SpaceA;' you can access all elements without typing SpaceA.
This is the case for class A, but I cannot see SpaceB without having to type SpaceA.SpaceB. Why is this?
Here is the code:

```
using System;

using SpaceA;

namespace SpaceA
{
    class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }

    namespace SpaceB
    {
        public class B
        {
            public B()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("B");
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace TestingCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //This does not work
            SpaceB.B x = new SpaceB.B();

            //This does work
            SpaceA.SpaceB.B y = new SpaceA.SpaceB.B();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Usually when you use 'using SpaceA;' you can access all elements without typing SpaceA.

Only the *direct* types which are members of `SpaceA`. A `namespace-or-type-name` is never resolved using a namespace in a normal `using` directive and then another "subnamespace" in the name. Note that this has nothing to do with how the types are declared (in terms of having a nested namespace declaration or just `namespace SpaceA.SpaceB`) - another example would be:

```
using System;

...
Xml.Linq.XElement x = null; // Invalid
```

See section 3.8 of the C# 5 specification for the precise details of how names are resolved.

One *slight* difference to this is if you have a using alias directive for a namespace, at which point that *can* be used to look up other namespaces

```
using X = System.Xml;
...
X.Linq.XElement x = null; // Valid
```